# What is the product of this piece of code in Python?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(int(sqrt(n))):
        x += 1
    for j in range( i, n):
        x += 1
```

I can't figure out the output.

Let's assume `n` and `x` are numbers, and use integers to represent them, what would it be?

Answer (score 0):

**Python's range() Parameters**

The range() function has two sets of parameters, as follows:

> range(stop)

stop: Number of integers (whole numbers) to generate, starting from zero. eg. `range(3) == [0, 1, 2]`.

> range([start], stop[, step])

- start: Starting number of the sequence.
- stop: Generate numbers up to,but not including this number.
- step: Difference between each number in the sequence

  # One parameter
   for i in range(5):
       print(i)

> ```
>    0
>    1
>    2
>    3
>    4
> ```

```
# Two parameters
 for i in range(3, 6):
     print(i)
```

> ```
>  3
>  4
>  5
> ```

```
 # Three parameters
 for i in range(4, 10, 2):
     print(i)
```

> ```
>  4
>  6
>  8
> ```

```
 # Going backwards
for i in range(0, -10, -2):
    print(i)
```

> ```
> 0
> -2
> -4
> -6
> -8
> ```

**Assignment operators**

Assignment operators are used in Python to assign values to variables.

`a = 5` is a simple assignment operator that assigns the value 5 on the right to the variable a on the left.

There are various compound operators in Python like `a += 5` that adds to the variable and later assigns the same. It is equivalent to `a = a + 5`.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that x is your output and the starting value of x is 0 and your input is n and i, then x would approximately be n*(√n+n-i)

Answer (score -1):

you can see the value by taking x and n as int.

```
import numpy as np
n=10
x=0

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(int(np.sqrt(n))):
        print (x)
        x += 1
    for j in range( i, n):
        print (x)
        x += 1
```